# Existence of an algebraic closure by Zorn's lemma

Tags: field-theory, set-theory, galois-theory

In gtm 167, *Field and Galois Theory* by Patrick Morandi, to prove the existence of an algebraic closure, the author states that one shall apply Zorn's lemma to find a maximal element once one has proved that for a field $K$ and a set $S$ containing $K$, if $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of all algebraic extension of $K$, then $K\subset L\subset F$ defines a partial order $L\leq F$.

It is easy to verify that the order is well-defined, yet according to Zorn's lemma, to apply it one must firstly find an upper bound for each chain of fields in $\mathcal{A}$, which seems not to be trivial. If $F$ is an upper bound of a chain, then there are no algebraic extension of $K$ except for $K$ itself, this by definition implies that $K$ is an algebraic closure. And this where I got stuck and it definitely doesn't follow the author's original proof. So could you please tell me where the problem is and what is the right way to apply Zorn's lemma?

Comment: It is not true that " If $F$ is an upper bound of a chain, then there are no algebraic extension of $K$ except for $K$ itself".

Comment: Looks like you got confused by what is an upper bound of a chain. If $(L_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$ is a chain of elements then take their union $L=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in I} L_{\alpha}$, and show it is an upper bound of the chain. (you have to show $L$ is a field which is contained in $S$, and is an algebraic extension of $K$) It doesn't imply by any means that $K$ has no algebraic extensions.

Comment: @Mark This is very clear, thanks!